# How to display Microsoft .doc or .docx formats in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, docx, doc

I'm trying to display word documents in a browser without relying on cloud transcoders such as google docs.

- For `.pdf` I use [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js)
- for odt I use [webodf](http://webodf.org)
- How can I display `.doc` ?
- How can I display `.docx` ?

I'm not interested in editing files, just viewing. And I'd prefer keeping the codec on the client-side, in (compiled) javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to directly show doc and docx documents in a browser, unless you first convert them on the server side, and then use a library like [WebODF](http://www.webodf.org) to display them in the browser.

You can use Node.js for such server-sided conversion, which makes it lightweight and cross-platform.